# How can I test if a html input type radio is checked

Tags: angular-spectator

I have this HTML in my component.html:

```
<input type="radio" [checked]="selected" (change)="select()" />
```

How can I make a Spectator query and expect to test if this input element is checked or not?

I have tried with:

```
expect(spectator.query('input')).toHaveAttribute('checked');
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: Expected element to have attribute 'checked', but had 'undefined'
```

And I have tried with:

```
expect(spectator.query('input')).toBeChecked();
```

But then I get the error:

```
Error: Expected element to be checked
```

How can I test this simple HTML input element?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expect(spectator.query('input')).toBeChecked();` is the correct usage.

It looks like `selected` property is false due to which radio button is not selected and you are getting this error. Simple **fix you binding** in test (by setting `selected` to true) or **update assertion** to check if radio button is not selected:

```
expect(spectator.query("input[type=radio]")).not.toBeChecked();
```

Take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-spectator-yvew6f) code sample where I have 2 bound radio buttons one selected and another not selected and I have tests for it.

```
it("should be checked", () => {
  spectator = createComponent();
  expect(spectator.query("#r1[type=radio]")).not.toBeChecked();
});

it("should not be checked", () => {
  spectator = createComponent();
  expect(spectator.query("#r2[type=radio]")).toBeChecked();
});
```

Also, take a look at [this guide](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator#custom-matchers) to see available custom matchers.

Comment: I needed to call this after I updated the component, I should have included the complete code: spectator.detectComponentChanges();